# How to work with complex data type on nested structs on Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

I want to create an app that manages customers for companies. Maybe is needed arrays or slices for this case. I created nested structs to manage customer but a new entry replaces the previous one. A part of my chaincode:

mychaincode.go

```
type CompanyInfo struct {
    ObjectType   string `json:"docType"`
    Company_Name string  `json:"company_name"`
    Customers        map[string][]Users `json:"customers"`
}

type Users  struct {
    Name         string `json:"name"`
    Surname      string `json:"surname"`
    Email        string `json:"email"`
}
func (c *MyChaincode) addCustomers(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    ObjectType := "Myobject"
    companyname := args[0]
    name := args[1]
    surname := args[2]
    email := args [3] 
    authUser := CompanyInfo{}
    authUser.Customers["key"] = []Users{
            {
                Name:         name,
                Surname:      surname,
                Email:        email,
            },
        }

    companyUser := CompanyInfo {objectType, companyname,authUser.Customers}
    companyUserJSONasBytes, err := json.Marshal(companyUser)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }

    err = stub.PutState(companyname, companyUserJSONasBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }
```

The visual studio does not recognize any error but when i am trying to invoke on local network the chaincode is exited

the output of docker logs dev-peer0.example.com-mychaincode-1.0:

> **panic: assignment to entry in nil map
> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference**

Comment: It looks like the code is simply wrong. check this line `struct1.Users = append(struct1.Users, struct2)`  Shouldn't it be added to `struct1.Customers`?

Comment: @myeongkil kim i think the best option is to use map nested slices. I updated my code and the error that I receive. I think that the nested slice is not receive values

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem needed to init the slice.

```
    authUser := CompanyInfo{}
    authUser.Customers = make(map[string][]Users)
    authUser.Customers["key"] = []Users{
            {
                Name:         name,
                Surname:      surname,
                Email:        email,
            },
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this, I have hardcoded the values but in you case you have to supply them.

```
users := []Users{
        Users{
            Name:    "Peter",
            Surname: "a",
            Email:   "a@mail.com",
        },
    }
    t := Users{
        Name:    "Pony",
        Surname: "b",
        Email:   "b@mail.com",
    }

    comp := CompanyInfo{}
    comp.ObjectType = "abc"
    comp.Company_Name = "company 1"
    comp.Customers = users
    comp.Customers = append(comp.Customers, t)
    fmt.Println(comp)
```

You can find the full example here https://play.golang.org/p/yfgxVhcwjYZ